# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent in middleware for joi validation

Tags: node.js, express, joi

I have created one middleware for joi validation error handling but it returns with some warning like **'Error: Can't set headers after they are sent'**

**Error:**

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\nodejs\bigfish\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\nodejs\bigfish\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\nodejs\bigfish\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at Object.JSONResponse [as JR] (D:\nodejs\bigfish\helpers\JsonResponse.js:3:29)
    at module.exports (D:\nodejs\bigfish\middlewares\error.js:8:14)
    at newFn (D:\nodejs\bigfish\node_modules\express-async-errors\index.js:12:20)
    at Layer.handle_error (D:\nodejs\bigfish\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\nodejs\bigfish\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
```

..

```
const express = require('express');
const Joi = require('joi');
const router = express.Router();
const HelperJoi = require('../helpers/joivalidation');
router.get('/GetRetailerDetails',VerifyToken, async (req,res) => {
    //Start Validation Code
    const schema = {
        RetailerId: Joi.number().required(),
    };
    HelperJoi.validate(req,res,schema);
    //End of Validation code      
});
```

**joivalidation.js** under helpers folder

```
const Joi = require('joi');
//This is Helper Function Module for Joi Validation
function JoiValidation(req,res,schema){
    const result = Joi.validate(req.query,schema, { abortEarly: false });
    if(result.error){
        //422 Validation Error
        var objError = [];    
        Object.keys(result.error.details).forEach(function(key) {
            objError.push(result.error.details[key]['message']);
        });
        return res.status(422).json({
            'statuscode': 422,
            'message': 'Validation Error',
            'responsedata': objError
        });
    }
}

module.exports.validate = JoiValidation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because the validator function returns a response in case of errors doesn't mean that the rest of the code isn't being run.

So you need to communicate back to the middleware that the validation failed, and the middleware should not continue.

For instance:

```
// middleware
if (! HelperJoi.validate(req,res,schema)) {
  // Validation failed, so we're done
  return;
}

// validator function
if (result.error) {
  ...
  res.status(422).json({
    'statuscode': 422,
    'message': 'Validation Error',
    'responsedata': objError
  });
  return false;
}
return true;
```

Another solution would be that the validator function would either return "null" in case of a positive validation, and an array of errors in case of a failed validation, and the middleware would return the 422 response itself. That would decouple the validator function.

Answer (score 0):

HelperJoi.validate is a function inside it you send a response and then return to the calling function which is the route handler and express try to terminate the requset and set to the headers which already sent. Either use the validation as a middleware or return the validation errors from HelperJoi.validate and respond from the route handler.

Answer (score 0):

Look like your implementation is wrong.

Example: How to implement `JOI` validation

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const joiHelper = require('../helpers/joiHelper');
router.get('/GetRetailerDetails',VerifyToken, async (req,res) => {

   let validationResult = joiHelper.JoiValidation(req.query, joiHelper.getRetailSchema(), {allowUnknown: false});
    if (validationResult.error) {
      return res.status(422).json({
            'statuscode': 422,
            'message': 'Validation Error',
            'responsedata': joiHelper.parseError(validationResult.error.details)
        });
    }    

    //Proceeds your get request
});
```

> joiHelper.js

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const joiHelper = {};

joiHelper.JoiValidation(object, schema, options = {}){
    return Joi.validate(object, schema, options);
};

joiHelper.parseError(errorObject) {
    let errorDetail = [];
    for (var key in errorObject) {
      errorDetail.push(errorObject[key].message);
    }
    return errorDetail.join(', ').replace(new RegExp('"','g'),'');
}
joiHelper.getRetailSchema () {
  const schemaObj = {
    RetailerId: Joi.number().required()
  };
  return Joi.object().keys(schemaObj);
};

module.exports = joiHelper;
```